# Limit of sum of uniformly distributed variables divided by N

Tags: random-variables, uniform-convergence

Would appreciate it if anyone could help me out with the following:
$U_i \sim Uniform(0,1) \ for\ i=1...N$ are N iid random variables. Show that 
$lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} log(U_i)}{N}=-1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the strong law of large numbers?

Comment: Figured it out thanks. I had to figure out that the expected value of log(U) is -1. I incorrectly thought it would be -1/4.

Comment: Good!  Glad you got it!